# Android Studio cannot inflate MapFragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm very new to Android dev. I'm using Android Studio 1.0.2 and I'm building a very simple App to display a Mapview.

I tried to follow several tutorials to implement it but I have always the same problem. The App crashes with the following error:

```
12-29 18:47:41.182    3574-3574/com.example.sebastien.myfirstandroidapp D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
12-29 18:47:41.183    3574-3574/com.example.sebastien.myfirstandroidapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sebastien.myfirstandroidapp, PID: 3574
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sebastien.myfirstandroidapp/com.example.sebastien.myfirstandroidapp.MapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
```

The layout contains only the following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

I have one more error:

> ```
>  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 6171000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
>         at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.E(Unknown Source)
>         at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
> ```

I will really appreciate any help or idea to be investigated to make this simple App running.

Comment: have you added google play services in your project?

Comment: try using a SupportMapFragment.

Comment: Looks like play services are missing from your project.

Answer (score 0):

> I will really appreciate any help or idea to be investigated to make this simple App running

You were given some very specific advice in the error:

```
The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 6171000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

This will give you a manifest akin to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.commonsware.android.mapsv2.basic"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="false"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <activity
            android:name="MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyC4iyT46cB00IdKGcy5EmAxK5uCOQX2Oy8"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <activity android:name="LegalNoticesActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

(from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Basic))